# Cmake Remove Cmake uninstall

Tags: linux, cmake

I want to ask a question to have a `Cmake uninstall` or `Cmake remove` command.
There were two different posts about this question at least 5 years ago. ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921017/cleaning-cmake-installed-files) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471620/cmake-support-make-uninstall) )
Additionally, there was [a source website](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#can-i-do-make-uninstall-with-cmake) that explains how `Cmake remove` can be done posted 2 years ago.
However, I couldn't follow the way I think because of the update on the file names.
Could you help me with uninstalling or removing software that is built by Cmake?

Edit: I couldn't try the approach that uses `install_manifest.txt` because I don't have that file. Instead, I have these files: `build.ninja` , `CMakeCache.txt`,  `cmake_install.cmake`,  `CPackConfig.cmake`.

Comment: "However, I couldn't follow the way I think because of the update on the file names." - I don't understand your problem. Do you have file `install_manifest.txt` in the build directory? If yes, then you should be able to apply any answer about uninstalling. If you don't have this file (and don't have a build directory), then CMake cannot help you in uninstalling things.

Comment: What is the difference of your question regarding the question you mentioned? Sounds like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @Tsyvarev No I don't have a text file named 'install_manifest.txt' but there are other text files with similar names. I thought those might have similar functionality.

Comment: "but there are other text files with similar names." - What exact other files "with similar names" do you have? Please, be **specific**. The file `install_manifest.txt` should be created after successful installation of the project. Have you performed such installation?

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes I have the same question. What should I do when the solution doesn't help me even if they are approved. Because a long time passed I post the same question. If I made a mistake about the rules of StackOverflow, sorry I didn't know.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I used the command 'cmake --build .' Command to install LLVM.
currently I have  text files named 
build.ninja
CMakeCache.txt
cmake_install.cmake
CPackConfig.cmake

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL If you had more reputation, you could start a bounty to get a more modern answer. But as far as I know, nothing changed. You have to make a clear explanation, why your question is no duplicate and why it adds value to this side.

Comment: `cmake --build .` performs **building**. For **installing** run `cmake --build --target install .`.

Comment: @usr1234567 'The answers are not solving the problem because the updated software ' is not enough? (I just thought it is because of the update, of course, it may not be. Specifically, how it can be done with Cmake 3.23.0)
What should I do when the approved question doesn't help me? (next time I can use that way if you tell me.)

Comment: @ÖmerGÜZEL: " 'The answers are not solving the problem because the updated software ' is not enough?" - No, this reason is not enough for post duplicates. You need to demonstrate (in the question post) that you have **tried specific approaches**, and they either do not work for you or not suitable for some other reasons. E.g. you could say "I have tried approach XXX, but it gives me `foo` instead of expected `bar`. Or "I have checked approach YYY, but it requires file `foo.txt` which I don't have". Simply saying that "I have tried everything but it doesn't work" is not enough.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Note that there's a shorter version for installing that does rely on the target name: `cmake --install .`

Comment: As for the question: Support for uninstall functionality doesn't seem to be provided, if you're installing from the build directory directly. It would be pretty hard to undo file creation done with `install(CODE)` Furthermore the files installed may change, if you modify the project. Moreover the `--prefix` option can result in installation to several directories and there could even be an overlap. If you want to provide a clean uninstall use `cpack` with a generator that generates a package for a package manager, e.g. `DEB`/`RPM` for linux targets and do the installation via that package.